An algorithm to match associative and commutative patterns
Background
For simplicity, just using ADD as an example.
In compiler backend, multiple addition is organized by combinations of multiple ADD instructions. For example ADD(1, ADD(1,3)).
But since it is associative and commutative, then it doesn't matter about the order and which 2 add first. Thus it can be seen as equivalent to ADD(1, 1, 3).
The problem lies on algorithm of searching the tree to find a valid subtree of pattern ADD(operand$0, operand$1, ...).
What I think
I'm thinking of the algorithm as follow:
bool try_switch(
    std::vector<NODE> &ret, 
    std::vector<NODE> &ops, 
    std::vector<NODE> &possible_shrink, 
    std::vector<NODE> &possible_grow
)
{
    for (NODE shrink ： possible_shrink) {
        for (NODE grow ： possible_grow) {
            // avoid duplicate
            if (!is_left_to_right(shrink, grow)) continue;
            swap_nodes(ret, shrink, grow);
            if (sub_nodes_match(ret, ops)) {
                return true;
            }
            // Due to the change of picked node, the possiblity of further swich will be adjusted
            Adjust_possible(shrink, grow, possible_shrink, possible_grow)
            if(try_switch(ret, ops, &possible_shrink, &possible_grow)) {
                return ture;
            }
            // Revert the adjustment
            swap_nodes(ret, grow, shrink);
            Adjust_possible(grow, shrink, possible_shrink, possible_grow)
        }
    }
    return false;
}
bool match_ADD(int num_of_ops, std::vector<NODE> ops) 
{
    std::vector<NODE> possible_shrink;
    std::vector<NODE> possible_grow;
    std::vector<NODE> ret = find_n_mins_one_ADD(num_of_ops, &possible_shrink, &possible_grow);
    if (sub_nodes_match(ret, ops)) {
        return true;
    }

    return try_switch(ret, ops, &possible_shrink, &possible_grow);
}

The key problem is that for some possible tree nodes, they can be an ADD or be an operand of ADD(operand$0, operand$1, ...).
What I'm thinking is to matching operand$0,...,operand$n I need exactly $n-1$ node of ADD in one sub-tree and matching all the leaves of this sub-tree to the targeted operand$i, if all of them matches, then the matching successes.
If not, I need to give up one node in founded sub-tree and replace it with new ADD node to form a new sub-tree, and check if all the leafs of the current sub-tree matches the operand$0, operand$1, ...
Also by doing the swap of nodes, it creates or removes new possibilities, thus I need to do a recursive call to fall back and try other possibilities.
Example
Assume we have a tree:
ADD(
    ADD(1,int_reg3),
    ADD(
        3,
        SUB(int_reg1, int_reg2)
    )
)

And we are trying to match a pattern ADD(int_val, int_val, SUB(int_val, int_val)) (register is also an int_val)
The algorithm will return:

ret=[1, int_reg3, ADD(3, SUB(int_reg1, int_reg2))]
possible_shrink = [ADD(1, int_reg3)]
possible_grow = [ADD(3, SUB(int_reg1, int_reg2))]

Now ret does not match the target pattern since there is no SUB
Then we will try another ADD node and remove one from current.
The only possibility of ADD node can remove from current sub-tree is ADD(1, int_reg3), and the only possible node can be added is ADD(3, SUB(int_reg1, int_reg2))
Thus we have:

ret=[ADD(1, int_reg3), 3, SUB(int_reg1, int_reg2)]
possible_shrink = [ADD(3, SUB(int_reg1, int_reg2)]
possible_grow = [ADD(1, int_reg3)]

Now the situation is:

ret matches the pattern ,return ture
If not, we notice that ADD(1, int_reg3) is to the left of ADD(3, SUB(int_reg1, int_reg2), duplicated. thus we exhausted the possibility and return false

Questions
If I'm not wrong, the correctness of the previous algorithm can be proved, but is it efficient??
Or if there is a better algorithm I do not know about??

TBH I don't understand some things. 1. "they can be an ADD or be an operand of ADD(operand$0, operand$1, ...)" ... what's the difference between those two operands? 2. I am not sure what are you trying to do. What does "match ... operations" mean? In case you want to collapse ADD(1, ADD(1, 3)) into ADD(1, 1, 3) can't you do that in a depth first traversal of the syntax tree? Most likely you mean something different though. I believe that giving one or two examples of what matching you need, should help.

@gthanop one example would be matching ADD(int_value, int_value, SUB(int_value, int_value)) and we have a tree like ADD(ADD(1,int_reg3),ADD(3,SUB(int_reg1, int_reg2))) (int_regi is register) so the matching sub-tree will be ADD(ADD(1,int_reg3), 3, SUB(int_reg1, int_reg2)). Now if only DFS search, the first ADD(1, int_reg3) will be treated as another ADD node, instead of leaf (operand) of the sub-tree

Ok, so now I understand that you are searching patterns within the syntax tree, just like you are saying in your last sentence of Background section (which I initially misunderstood). Something like applying a regular expression (eg ADD(value, value, SUB(value, value))) to the literal ADD(ADD(1, 2), SUB(3, 4)) let's say. Or maybe a bit more complex NFA let's say, since associative and commutative operators can be collapsed. Since you are only searching, the original syntax tree must not be modified (where "making a copy if needed", is implied here).

@gthanop Thanks, but the structure is actually a binary tree. So I'm searching the valid pattern on a binary tree. Maybe I can also apply NFA but it kind of hard for me to do it. Could you be so kind to provide more details??

As far as I remember, Nondeterministic Finite Automata (NFAs) is how regular expressions (aka regexes) in particular are matched against input literals. Sorry for the abbreviations so far. To be honest, it's been a long time since I practiced such things, so I am not really certain right now on how to apply them for your case, but I was thinking they may be applicable from a high level perspective. My previous comment serves more like an idea to solve your case, if applicable. I just had in mind that the binary tree structure may still be used as a literal. ...(to be continued)...

... For example the tree you gave in your question's example may form the literal string "ADD(ADD(1, int_reg3), ADD(3, SUB(int_reg1, int_reg2)))". Since regular expressions are matched against literals, then so could be ADD(value, value, SUB(value, value)) matched against the tree. At least in theory this seems possible to me. I was also thinking that you don't have to use actual string objects to represent your trees (avoiding performance penalties of converting to/from strings). At least that was what I was thinking, it may very well be wrong.

@gthanop I may think it in this way. The NFA can be used to create AST from string. and it can do it by reduction of tokens. each valid reduction creates a node on AST. So to create a 3 node pattern of ADD(a,b,c) we may have to write all possible production equations as ADDs(a, b, c) = ADD(ADD(a,b), c) | ADD(a, ADD(b, c))??

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Given that you already have a valid tree of expressions you can join Adds or Muls with a simple recursive algorithm.
The algorithm works in linear time and is purely a bottom up pattern matching simplifier.
I leave it to you to figure out how to write it in C++.
The order of the nodes does not matter.
ADD(ADD(x, y), z)
ADD(x, ADD(y, z))

Both of these will be simplified to ADD(x, y, z) because you're going over all children, flattening them first, and then collecting their arguments if they are the same operation.
def flatten_expr(expr):
    match expr:
        case Add(args):
            flattened = []
            for arg in args:
                flat_arg = flatten_expr(arg)  # recursive call
                match flat_arg:
                    case Add(nested_args):
                        flattened.extend(nested_args)
                    case _:
                        flattened.append(flat_arg)
            return Add(flattened)
        case Mul(args):
            flattened = []
            for arg in args:
                flat_arg = flatten_expr(arg)  # recursive call
                match flat_arg:
                    case Mul(nested_args):
                        flattened.extend(nested_args)
                    case _:
                        flattened.append(flat_arg)
            return Mul(flattened)
        case _:
            return expr


Hi thanks for answering. I think it is equivalent of linearizing all the ADD sub-node and try possibilities if I can avoid duplicating cases. And by linearizing, I also have to keep the tree structure, for example ADD(a, ADD(b, c)) does not have sub-tree that matching ADD(a, c), but has for ADD(a, value). And by only testing the leaves of linearizing of a, b, c, I cannot conclude that ADD(a, c) doesn't match
